# why I can't see the option to edit code inline and handler Info on after creating the AWS Lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

These the things that I can see after creating the lambda function.
If I tried to edit the code then that is not reflected after testing the lambda function because the code action is not in edit Inline mode and save button is also not visible.

[This is how lambda function Console is looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIUmS.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There are two usual causes for that:

1. You are looking at specific **lambda version**. Lambda versions are **immutable** and can't be changed.
2. You are **not deploying** your changes. In the new UI, there is no 'Save' button. Instead there is orange `Deploy` button.